# How to add JavaScript custom pup-up boxes for ToDo App? (+Video Explanation)

Tags: javascript, popup, frontend

I'm new to programming and I'm building a ToDo app in JavaScript. I know how to add new tasks to a list. But, I would like to create a new separate box for each task, so when someone clicks on the task a new box opens up with more info about the task. Just like here:

https://youtu.be/udE2TZtClPU

I tried alert boxes and other things, but I can not achieve the desired result. The custom boxes that are opening up and darkening the background in the video, are a perfect example. How can I achieve that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @spireski93, welcome to SO. Have a look at this link for how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're trying to make is called a modal box.

[Here is a tutorial to get you started.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)